# Is there a temporary fix for a deprecated module that prevents cron from running?

Tags: 8

I have a client D8 site that is using the Field Collections module, which is no longer supported. We are working on migrating Field Collections to Paragraphs, but in the meantime the Field Collections module is throwing an error that prevents the cron from running:

> Message   Error: Call to a member function isDefaultRevision() on null in Drupal\field_collection\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\FieldCollectionListFormatter->viewElements() (line 45 of /code/modules/field_collection/src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/FieldCollectionListFormatter.php)

I'm looking for a temporary workaround for this issue that will allow the cron to run while we're getting everything moved over to Paragraphs. Some kind of patch to Field Collections? A preprocess function that bypasses the issue for this particular instance? Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you change/patch [the named line](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/field_collection/-/blob/8.x-1.0-alpha1/src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/FieldCollectionListFormatter.php#L45) to `if ($field_collection_item && $field_collection_item->isDefaultRevision()) {`?

Comment: Do you manage your site with Composer? Contrib modules are better to be put in modules/contrib and custom modules then in modules/custom.

Comment: Thanks @leymannx, that was an elegant and straightforward solution (and one I am embarrassed that I didn't think of myself). Regarding your Composer question: I generally manage sites with Composer, but I inherited this particular site, the original developers did not use Composer, and rearranging things is out of scope for my role. ;)